# How to configure nginx to enable kinda 'file browser' mode?

Tags: nginx

Once I've seen this before when I type a URL `http://test.com/test/`, instead of give me a html page, it gives me a 'file browser' like interface to browse all the files in the given location.

I think it maybe a nginx module that could be enable in the location context.

The `nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  122.97.248.252;
                location /test {
                        root /home/yozloy/html/;
                        autoindex on;
                }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

update the `error.log`

> 2012/05/19 20:48:33 [error] 20357#0: *72 open() "/home/yozloy/html/test" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 125.43.236.33, server: 122.97.248.252, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", host: "unicom2.markson.hk

I must misunderstand the location `/test` mean, I thought it meant when I type http://example.com/test, then it would access the root dictionary which is `/home/yozloy/html/`

Comment: does the test directory exist?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov test directory doesn't exist, I thought /test only means in the url, so i can direct to the root directory, and I don't want to make a test dictionary, I must misunderstand it, but how I can make it right?

Comment: would you just create /home/yozloy/html/test directory and populate it somehow just to see if autoindex works?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov thanks it works when I create the test folder.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You should try [ngx_http_autoindex_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html).

Set `autoindex` option to `on`. It is `off` by default.

Your example configuration should be ok

```
location /{ 
   root /home/yozloy/html/; 
   index index.html; 
   autoindex on;
}
```

Without `autoindex` option you should be getting Error 403 for requests that end with `/` on directories that do not have an `index.html` file. With this option you should be getting a simple listing:

```html
<html>
<head><title>Index of /</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /test/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="test.txt">test.txt</a>                 19-May-2012 10:43            0
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Updated the listing to delete any references to test

Comment: It seems promising. But I can't make it work I put the related directive here `location /{ root /home/yozloy/html/; index index.html; autoindex on;}`

Comment: Please check that you restarted nginx and that nginx was not compiled with --without-http_autoindex_module

Comment: I remember the only flag I gave is --with-mp4_module, does this means http_autoindex_module is installed by default? or Do I have some command to check if I've installed it of not

Comment: `nginx -V` should give you the list of configured options. Note that autoindex is enabled by default. So if --without-autoindex is not there then it's ok.

Comment: bogon:conf markson$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.0.11
bogon:conf markson$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.0.11
built by gcc 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
configure arguments: --with-http_mp4_module
bogon:conf markson$

Comment: I assume you are getting HTTP 403 instead of the list of files, am I correct?

Comment: Please check the error log then and update the question. This is getting too long a discussion. I'd move it to chat.

Comment: I am getting HTTP 304 instead

Comment: @Roland this is usually caused by requests with `If-Modified-Since` header and means that the catalogue was not modified. Are you executing requests from a browser? Can you examine the request headers?

Comment: @DimaChubarov you might be right, thanks. I was suspecting a possible mixup between 304 and 403. But I fixed my problems, so I will not investigate this further

Answer (score 41):

All answers contain part of the answer. Let me try to combine all in one.

**Quick setup "file browser" mode on freshly installed nginx server:**

1. Edit default config for nginx:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
   ```
2. Add following to config section:

   ```
   location /myfolder {  # new url path
      alias /home/username/myfolder/; # directory to list
      autoindex on;
   }
   ```
3. Create folder and sample file there:

   ```
   mkdir -p /home/username/myfolder/
   ls -la >/home/username/myfolder/mytestfile.txt
   ```
4. Restart nginx

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart nginx
   ```
5. Check result: `http://<your-server-ip>/myfolder` for example http://192.168.0.10/myfolder/

[image]

Comment: If someone is looking for the default config file in the windows version: You have to search for `\nginx-1.xx.y\conf\nginx.conf`. If you want to add the folder C:\Temp as alias directory, you have to use this syntax with forward slashes: `C:/Temp/` - otherwise you will find an error like `invalid number of arguments in "alias" directive` in your `\logs\error.log` file

Answer (score 17):

### 1. List content of all directories

Set autoindex option to `on`. It is off by default.

Your configuration file ( `vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` ) should be like this

```
location /{ 
   ... ( some other lines )
   autoindex on;
   ... ( some other lines )
}
```

### 2. List content of only some specific directory

Set autoindex option to `on`. It is off by default.

Your configuration file ( `vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` ) 
should be like this.
change `path_of_your_directory` to your directory path

```
location /path_of_your_directory{ 
   ... ( some other lines )
   autoindex on;
   ... ( some other lines )
}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: The `location /<something>` is the url to access the files you want to share (for example  `/data`), not the directory you wish to share via nginx (for example `~/videos/funny-cats/`).

Answer (score 6):

You need create `/home/yozloy/html/test` folder. Or you can use `alias` like below show:

```
location /test {
    alias /home/yozloy/html/;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've tried many times.

And at last I just put `autoindex on;` in `http` but outside of `server`, and it's OK.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this section to server, just before the `location / {`

```
location /your/folder/to/browse/ {
        autoindex on;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    # Listen on http port
    listen 80;

    # Serve files listing
    location ^~ /files/ {
        # Path to serve (Trailing slash is important)
        alias /home/user/downloads/;

        # File listing (index) in json format
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_format json;
        autoindex_exact_size on;
    }

    # Serve root html/js/css files
    location / {
        # Path where index.html is
        root /var/www/files/;
        # Try files makes nginx serves root files on all sub-paths
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

With this you get the `index.html` file from `/var/www/files/` for all sub-path `http://example.com/a`, `http://example.com/a/b` and you can get the file listing for directories by adding `/files/` at the end of the url.

I made [nginx-explorer](https://github.com/izissise/nginx-explorer) around this behavior