# HTTPServer only on a certain directory of project - NGINX

Tags: laravel, http, nginx, ftp, webserver

## Goal

My goal is to see something like this, when I visit a certain URL of my app :

[image]

---

## Try

```
location /backup {
    autoindex on;
    index index.html; 
    root /home/app/public/backup;
}
```

## Result

[image]

---

## Config

My entire `vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root /home/app/public;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location /backup {
        autoindex on;
        index index.html;
        root /home/app/public/backup;
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that FTP access? It looks more like HTTP with [directory listing enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663248/how-to-configure-nginx-to-enable-kinda-file-browser-mode).

Comment: I have tried `autoindex on;` already still not happening. What could it be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your configuration, `nginx` is trying to locate `/home/app/public/backup/backup` path, hence `404`.

These 3 solutions will work for you

```
# remove root directive (recommended in your case)
location /backup {
    autoindex on;
    index index.html;
    #root /home/app/public/backup;
}

# set root to public (redundant since already done)
location /backup {
    autoindex on;
    index index.html;
    root /home/app/public;
}

# replace root with alias
location /backup {
    autoindex on;
    index index.html;
    alias /home/app/public/backup/;
}
```

For more information check how [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) work, you can also read how `nginx` [handles user requests](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms)