# NGINX 403 error with autoindex

Tags: nginx, permissions, http-status-code-403, mod-autoindex

I want to have NGINX do an auto index of a directory (\var\www\HTML\archive). This on a raspberry pi.

Here is the NGINX.conf bit relating to users, servers, and locations

```
#user www-data;
#user nginx;
user pi;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
...
server{
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location /archive/ {
       root /var/www/html;
       index index.html;
       autoindex on;
       }

    }
```

By the way, I tried all different users - including root!

In the error log I have:

```
2018/06/08 23:35:07 [error] 22477#22477: *2 directory index of "/var/www/html/archive/" is forbidden, client: 10.0.0.6, server: _, request: "GET /archive/ HTTP/1.1", host: "10.0.0.16"
```

But I did all the chmod g+s, chmod 644 for files etc.

```
pi@fridge-monitor:/var/www/html $ ls -al
total 24
drwxrwsr-x 4 root nginx 4096 Jun  8 11:57 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 root nginx 4096 Jun  2 18:41 ..
drwxr-sr-x 2 pi   nginx 4096 Jun  8 12:59 archive
drwxr-sr-x 2 pi   nginx 4096 Jun  8 10:53 dynamic
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   nginx 2653 Jun  8 10:50 index.html

pi@fridge-monitor:/var/www/html $ ls -al archive
total 168
drwxr-sr-x 2 pi   nginx  4096 Jun  8 12:59 .
drwxrwsr-x 4 root nginx  4096 Jun  8 11:57 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   nginx 38113 Jun  8 12:41 1d.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   nginx   366 Jun  8 12:41 table.html
```

I believe that the upper directories are OK as well:

```
pi@fridge-monitor:/var/www/html $ namei -l /var/www/html/archive
f: /var/www/html/archive
drwxr-xr-x root root  /
drwxr-xr-x root root  var
drwxrwsr-x root nginx www
drwxrwsr-x root nginx html
drwxr-sr-x pi   nginx archive
```

I *can* see the files in /archive/ for example if I go 10.0.0.16/archive/1d.png then the graphic is displayed.

Having followed some steps in other posts:

```
[pid  4222] stat64("/var/www/html/archive/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0

[pid  4222] stat64("/var/www/html/archive/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0

[pid  4222] stat64("/var/www/html/archive/index.html", 0x7efe1750) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

[pid  4222] stat64("/var/www/html/archive", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0

[pid  4222] stat64("/var/www/html/archive/index.htm", 0x7efe1750) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

[pid  4222] stat64("/var/www/html/archive/index.nginx-debian.html", 0x7efe1750) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

[pid  4222] stat64("/var/www/html/archive/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0

[pid  4222] stat64("/var/www/html/archive/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Are there any other `server` blocks in your configuration? You can see which files `nginx` is actually reading by using `nginx -T`

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I dont think so but I'm totally new to running a server. I'll post the whole config (removed comments for clarity:

Comment: Plus i ran the nginx -T and it does show my config file that i have been editing.

I dont know if it's relevant but after the config file it lists a bunch of modules and autoindex is not amongst them. is it possible that it's not installed??

Comment: You are restarting `nginx` after you edit its config file? Also, please edit your question and add relevant information there.

Comment: yes i am restarting every time. i actually have a solution...

Answer (score -1):

needed to add a command to the html section above the server!

```
autoindex on;
```

working fine now!
thanks to @RichardSmith for the good will

credit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663248/how-to-configure-nginx-to-enable-kinda-file-browser-mode)

my config now starts:

```
user pi;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    autoindex on;    **** <--- HERE
...
```

Comment: note this seems to have switched on autoindex for the whole site.
it's not important for me but be aware!